# If $f$ is the identical function, then the inverse of $f: X\to X$ is not continuous if the second space isn't discrete

Tags: general-topology, continuity

My book defines a function $f:X\to Y$ as continuous in $a\in X$ if for every neighbourhood $V$ of $f(a)\in Y$ exists a neighbourhood of $a$ so that $f(U) \subset V$. The equivalent: if $V$ is the neighbourhood of $f(a)$ then the inverse of $f$ is the neighbourhood of $a$.

Now it states the following:

> The identical function $f:X\to X$ of the discrete topological space $X$ to topological space $X$ of any topology is continuous, the reverse function isn't continuous if the second topology isn't discrete.

I do not understand why. Any clarification available?

Comment: Instead of "identical function", it should be "identity function". This is a common usage issue with mathematical English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $g : (X,\tau_1) \to (X,\tau_2)$ is the identity map, $\tau_2$ is the discrete topology, and $\tau_1$ is not the discrete topology. Since $\tau_1$ is not the discrete topology, there is a set $A \subset X$ such that $A \not \in \tau_1$. Since $\tau_2$ *is* the discrete topology, $A \in \tau_2$. Now $g^{-1}(A)=A$, since $g$ is the identity map, so we have a set in $\tau_2$ whose inverse image is not in $\tau_1$. Hence $g$ is not continuous.

The reverse happens when we switch the roles of $\tau_1$ and $\tau_2$. That is, $(g^{-1})^{-1}(A)=A$ still holds but now if $A \in \tau_1$ then $A \in \tau_2$, so $g^{-1}$ is continuous.

Comment: I don't understand how A⊂X A∉τ1 , but A∈τ2 if the typologies are as you said when most typologies are "richer" than the discrete.

Comment: The OP contains its (valid) definition of a continous function, so you should write an answer according to this definition and not simply reproduce a standard proof

Comment: @BozoVulicevic You have it backwards. In a discrete topological space, *every* subset is open.

Comment: Do you state A⊂X A∈τ2 and A∉τ1 because all subsets of the discrete space are part of the typology? This is not the case with others like R?

Comment: @BozoVulicevic Maybe a concrete example will help. $\mathbb{N}$ as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}$ is discrete. This is because each singleton $\{ n \}$ is open, because it can be written as $\mathbb{N} \cap (n-1/2,n+1/2)$. Since each singleton is open, every subset is open, since every subset can be written as a union of singletons. This is the definition of a discrete space, and does not happen in the case of a non-discrete space such as $\mathbb{R}$ itself.